# Rails with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

Running rails application with heroku, for the last one month we are getting memory quota exceeded(R14) issues and hardly trying to find the root cause but didn't get any exact reason? is it because of web_concurrency? also we are using new_relic

Rails : 3.2.22

Ruby: 1.9.3

server: unicorn, WEB_CONCURRENCY is 5

As a total of 20 dynos we are using, and managing with process scheduler

[image]

Comment: Probably, the app is leaking memory. Since you are using new relic, see their log to check memory usage chart. If chart is still showing memory increase (not saturating) even after a long time(probably a few hours or a day) after you restarted the dynos, then it is leaking memory. If that's the case, then I don't know if someone can help you without the full source code. I have had hard time hunting these. First suggestion will be upgrade to Ruby 2.x if possible. It has huge improvement in garbage collection over 1.9.x

Answer (score 0):

Your entire RoR stack is pretty much outdated and Heroku now endorses Puma as its preferable server, which eats much less memory (you can check their benchmark at at http://puma.io/)
[puma benchmark](https://i.stack.imgur.com/voIho.png)

Nevertheless, if the problem started out of nowhere I would rather search for the gems or piece of code that is either causing such memory consumption (activeadmin, rmagick, etc). Also, a rapid but more expensive solution would be increasing your  dyno (Performance-L or Performance-M)
As WEB_CONCURRENCY try to lower it and check if this solves the R14 problem

Comment: Yes with puma, but we have make sure that our code thread-safe right?

Comment: You use Rails 3.2.22, so the base framework is thread safe at least. It seams to me, that you are just trying to make a legacy rails app "just work". 
You can solve your issue by adding hw or improving sw. The software one (upgrading the ruby version, the rails framework and using puma (instead of unicorn) will alleviate much of ur problem. If you don't have time right now, your best shot is increasing your dyno performance. If it is a memory leak problem, from time to time you will be annoyed by the R14 thing. The only difference is that the delta will be higher, with better dynos